# how to implement online searching in android studio

Tags: android, search

I would like to implement online searching , or global searching in my application.For example, the input will search and get result from google or any other search engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        String keyword= "your search";
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, keyword);
        startActivity(intent);
```

It will lead to google search engine.